# How can I change the color of a Geometry Drawing, defined within a Button Backgroung, when the button is hovered over in XAML?

Tags: .net, wpf, xaml

I tried,,, many different ways, did some research, could NOT find an answer anywhere or find a way to make it work. I'm pretty new to WPF so I may have taken on more than I can chew rn but still, here's the code:

```
<Button x:Name="_0" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Click="Button_Click" Width="100" Height="100" BorderThickness="0,0,0,0" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="3">
    <Button.Foreground>
        <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1.5" StartPoint="0.5,0">
            <GradientStop Color="#FFC850C8"/>
            <GradientStop Color="#FF8C50FF" Offset="1"/>
        </LinearGradientBrush>
    </Button.Foreground>
    <Button.Background>
        <DrawingBrush>
            <DrawingBrush.Drawing>
                <GeometryDrawing Brush="#FFA2A2A2">
                    <GeometryDrawing.Geometry>
                        <EllipseGeometry Center="50,50" RadiusX="45" RadiusY="20"/>
                    </GeometryDrawing.Geometry>
                    <GeometryDrawing.Pen>
                        <Pen>
                            <Pen.Brush>
                                <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                                    <GradientStop Color="#FF8C50F0"/>
                                    <GradientStop Color="#FFC850C8" Offset="1"/>
                                </LinearGradientBrush>
                            </Pen.Brush>
                        </Pen>
                    </GeometryDrawing.Pen>
                </GeometryDrawing>
            </DrawingBrush.Drawing>
        </DrawingBrush>
    </Button.Background>
    <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="0" FontSize="72" FontFamily="Bahnschrift SemiBold" Margin="0,10,0,0"/>
</Button>
```

[While not on hover, looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rIOHr.png)
[On Hover, looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N8eli.png)

When what I *want* to do is to make it so whenever I hover over the button, it just darkens the color inside the circle a bit. All I managed to do was break the hover and make it so nothing changes when u hover over it tho which is not ideal lol, especially when it wasn't intentional and just me breaking the code by accident

I tried using the  tags but I couldn't figure out how to tie it to the Brush inside DrawingBrush.Drawing.GeometryDrawing. Tried using  outside the Background definition, tried setting the value to uh. All that code inside Background.Style, but it won't let you do that

So yeah I'm kind of at a loss as to what I can even try at this point

Comment: The background Brush when hovered is defined by default Template. You need to set custom `ControlTemplate` to Template in order to override it.